# Single record buffering in SAP ABAP

Tags: abap

My table is `stud`.

```
+-----+------+-------+
| no  | name | grade |
+-----+------+-------+
| 101 | naga | A     | 
| 102 | raj  | A     |
| 103 | john | A     |
+-----+------+-------+
```

The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT * FROM stud WHERE no = 101 AND grade = 'A'.
```

If am using single record buffering, how much data is being stored in the buffer area?

Answer (score 2):

This query doesn't do anything.  There is no "into" clause. meaning it wont store anything selected.

You are probably looking to do something like this....

```
SELECT * FROM stud into wa_stud WHERE no = 101 AND grade = 'A'.
  "processing of each single row is performed here
endselect.
```

or perhaps something like this, where only 1 row (the first rows ordered by primary key) is selected...

```
select single * from stud into wa_stud where no = 101 and grade = 'A' .
```

or perhaps you want everything brought in to a table, meaning number and grade does not include the full primary key.

```
 select * from stud into table it_stud where no = 101 and grade = 'A'.
```

Comment: The usage of the `into`-clause is recommended, but not necessary.  You can omit the into-clause if you define your table with `tables stud.`.

Comment: Ah yes.  In that case he just needs the endselect statement.

Comment: >...or a `select single...`

Answer (score 1):

this is from ABAP Keyword documentation in SE38:

> SAP Buffer - Single Record Buffering
>
> Only those rows in the table are buffered that are actually accessed. 
>   This requires less space in the buffer than when using generic or full
>   buffering. On the other hand, more administration work is required and
>   significantly more direct database accesses.

So since your query returns a single record (based on the data you displayed) it should just get one row and hold in the buffer.

I'd suggest looking at SAP help and Google - also have a look at SELECT SINGLE and incompletely specified keys - there used to be a problem with the buffer being bypassed in some situations - have a read for reference.